# One of my two RAMs is not working now.Is it because I removed it when power wasw on?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I had problem in my pc that kept hanging n display pixels were set bad.
I removed my both RAMs when **power was on**(pc was **shut down**).

After I reinserted them, one of them works and other is not(it beeps when I insert it).
I tried it 6-8 times to ensure that it is fitted properly.

Why is this beeping? memory failed due to "power on" or something else?

Comment: The PC got to be unplugged before you start the maintenance measures.

Answer (score 3):

Your mainboard has some voltage on it, if your PC is shutdown but the PSU still switched on.
This is to support features like "wake on LAN" and other stuff.

I have often exchanged parts in my computer with the PSU on and nothing happened, but it is always a better idea to switch it completely off, because you can't know which parts are under current while you are removing them. (and this still does not mean that they have to break, but they can. its like defusing a bomb, green cable first)

You can look up what the beep codes tell you, they are normaly a sequence of some long and short beeps that help indicate what is wrong. (bad memory, bad vga etc)

Here is one [site](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm), be aware that different BIOS' have different codes,but there are not that many BIOS Vendors and the codes are mostly very similar.

Comment: My pc works with second RAM.so I don't think beeps indicate any other problem.

Comment: Is there any way to decide that my RAM is now failed that cannot be used again?

Comment: Any symptoms that shows failure due to "power on"???

Comment: then you probably have wrecked the other one. like i said, its like defusing a bomb, if you pull the wrong side out first (i dont want to imply that there is a right side) you can destroy your board. other possibility is, that by pulling the ram out you connected two pins inside the slot and burned away a part of the mainboard. (like the controller for the second slot or something) there are a lot of possibilites.

Comment: to decide if it is broken. put it into the computer alone. put it in the first slot nearest to the CPU. if you get the same beeps it prolly is not usable any more.

Comment: and turn the PSU off this time :P

Comment: ya..n how do I decide that it is because of "power on"?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the pixel-problems after you removed it? It is really hard to tell if it got destroyed by pulling it out, especially if it was kind of broken before.

Comment: now pc is working good with another RAM which did not fail.can u guess the cause of pc hanging & pixel getting distorted?

Comment: @Akash Walter is not your personal computer support technician. If you have a question, please ask it properly on this site, and provide *much* more information about it. Use the amount of detail in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/371060/screen-fuzzes-zig-zags-on-a-custom-build) as a template.