# Using WiFi card without Antenna together with RTX 2080

Tags: wireless-networking, graphics-card, display, adapter

My setup is the following:

1. Motherboard: MSI B450-M2 PRO
2. AMD Ryzen 2700X NVidia RTX 2080
3. Ubuntu 18.04
4. TP-Link TL-WN881ND (300Mbps PCI-E wifi card)
5. The monitor is rather old, connection to PC is via adapter:

   - PC's DisplayPort ->
   - DisplayPort<>VGA adapter ->
   - Monitor's VGA port

When I plug external antennae into wifi card, I observe screen constant flickering and sometimes blackout lasting for several seconds. When I remove antennae, screen works ok and wifi is working too! (Luckily, wifi router is nearby, right behind the wall.)

1. Why does connecting antennae causes monitor malfunction?

   - connecting to another monitor directly via HDMI solves the problem, so the problem is most probably due to adapter
2. Is it safe for wifi card to not use antennae if I still want to use the old monitor (which implies using adapter)?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/371060/screen-fuzzes-zig-zags-on-a-custom-build?rq=1

Comment: DisplayPort-to-VGA might be a bit extreme. Can you do DVI-to-VGA or HDMI-to-VGA? Try also to put some distance between cables, including mains power cable. Is the old monitor LCD?

Comment: There is DVI port on videocard, but I can try HDMI-to-VGA, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, the adapter is the problem and you should get a better one. A properly made cable or adapter should be insulated and imune to this kind of interference.

1. With the antenna there's an increase of TX/RX that causes the analogue noise/interferences in the nearby analogue part of the adapter. Digital signals like HDMI in a proper cable are unaffected by by nearby Wifi or Bluetooth sources.
2. It's safe to use the WiFi without antennae, if still within range. But, again, the better solution is to get a proper adapter if you intend to use the old monitor.